# Image doesn't appear when changing its source in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-phone-8

When I want to change an image's source, the image simply disappears.

The code I'm using:

```
tactImg.Source=tactImgList[i];

tactImgList = new BitmapImage[32];
tactImgList[0] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Images/1.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I need to add to an xaml file or I'm making the global array wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ms-appx in Windows Phone 8 projects , it's for WinRT projects.

Make sure your image's Build type is Content , remove the ms-appx part and since your image has relative uri , set your UriKind to Relative.

Answer (score 0):

First, fill in the data, and then change the source.

`tactImgList = new BitmapImage[32];
tactImgList[0] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Images/1.png", UriKind.Absolute));
tactImg.Source=tactImgList[i];`

Or use `ObservableCollection` for storing images.